# Ember.js root view won't render on refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing, ember.js-view

I have a root template with an outlet and then a nested dynamic resource. When you enter a name into an input in the root view, an ajax request will asynchronously retrieve a model for nested dynamic resource and render a template using information from that model. It's all working fine when I start from the root and use the input to call the nested resource.

So everything is working perfectly, and the nested resource updates the url, but when I refresh or paste the url into the nav bar I just get a blank page. No errors but no HTML at all. I have verified that the ajax request is successful and my model is created. As far as I can tell the root template is not rendered, and so my nested template has no place to go.

I thought ember was supposed to make this easy and automatic, how do I make the root template render when I am going directly to a nested route?

Here is the router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('app', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.resource('user', {path: ':screen_name'});
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('app');
  }
});

App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var that = this;
    var promise = Ember.$.getJSON('/users/new?screen_name=' + params['screen_name']);

    promise.then(fulfill, reject);

    function fulfill (answer) {
      return that.store.createRecord('user', answer);
    }

    function reject (reason) {
      console.log("failure");
      return false;
    }

    return promise;
  },

  serialize: function(user) {
    return {screen_name: user.get('user.screen_name')};
  }
});
```

Here is the `AppController`:

```
App.AppController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    findUser: function(){
      var that = this;
      var name = that.get('screen_name');
      that.set('screen_name', '');
      that.transitionToRoute('user', name);
    }
  },

  screen_name: ''
});

App.AppIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "app",
  app: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.app")
});
```

Here is the `UserController`:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: "app",

  backgroundPic: function(){
    return this.get('model.user.profile_banner_url');
  }.property('model.user.profile_banner_url'),

  profilePic: function(){
    return this.get('model.user.profile_image_url');
  }.property('model.user.profile_image_url')
});
```

Here is the `user` model, it just accepts the JSON object that is returned by the AJAX request:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend();
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `$.getJSON` and Ember Data?

Comment: Either way, it'd be nice to see what that json looks like, additionally what your user ds model looks like.  If you can replicate the problem in a jsbin, it really helps.  Here's one with some of your code dropped into it.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/175/edit

Comment: It interfaces with the Twitter API. The ajax request goes to my server, and the server makes the request because it needs to go through oAuth with secret keys that I can't expose in the javascript. The resulting json object is very complex, and I can't expose the keys on jsbin. It all works fine, it is just when I refresh after I render the user template, the root template doesn't seem to load. The ajax request goes through and the model gets created, but the page is totally empty.

Comment: the problem speaks to a model hook issue, it's a little difficult to diagnose without some semblance of the json.  Additionally it could be template related if it works when transition to is invoked, but not when you refresh.  So the templates could help as well.